# IE 6 issue - page not found

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to access my application (in asp.net iis6 .Net-4.0) on IE6. The login page is displayed but just after loading, error page is shown (the page could not be found). Is there any problem in machine config ? Any idea. It is working fine in other browsers

Update 1: I saw c:\windows\system32\shdoclc.dll/http_400 on taskbar of IE6.

Comment: Its coming on all IE6. I tried different machines.

Comment: [400 error](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html)

Comment: Is this really an IE6 issue? does it work differently in other browsers?

Comment: Yes. The application is working perfectly on other browsers

Comment: Time to get your consumers off MSIE6.

Comment: The question is fine and i guess many people must be facing same problem for IE6 when the paht of application is changed and there is file iepng.htc included in the css for same.

Comment: If anyone anytime is helped by this post, kindly write a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. To have the application work properly on ie6, there was iepng__.htc which did not have correct path. Issue resolved after resolving the path. This issue was just on IE6 as this works only for it.